# Key function in data binding: objects vs strings

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When binding data using `d3.selectAll(...).data(mydata, key_fn)`, I expect all keys that match previously bound data to end up in the `update` selection (as opposed to `enter()` or `exit()`), but I am finding that's not the case if the previously bound data is a string and the newly bound data is an object. **Is this expected behavior? If so, can someone explain why?**

Here's an example of what I mean, using D3.js v5.15.0 in Chrome JS console:

```js
// Setup some data arrays, one with strings and one with objects using the same string values
    strings_only = ['A','B','C'];
    objects_with_values = [{key:'A',value:1},{key:'B',value:2},{key:'C',value:3}];
    
    // Bind the string data to the DOM with string values as keys
    d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
        .data(strings_only, d => d)
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class','test');

    // Bind again with the strings and I get the expected behavior
    selection_strings_only = d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
        .data(strings_only, d => d);
    console.log(selection_strings_only.size() == strings_only.length); // PASS
    console.log(selection_strings_only.enter().size() == 0); // PASS
    
    // Bind with the objects (same key value) and they end up in the enter() selection
    selection_objects_with_values = d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
        .data(objects_with_values, d => d.key);
    console.log(selection_objects_with_values.size() == strings_only.length); // FAIL
    console.log(selection_objects_with_values.enter().size() == 0); // FAIL
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If my initial data is an array of objects instead of strings (e.g. `[{key:'A'},{key:'B'},{key:C}]`), then the update with new objects works as expected, so I am able to work around this issue, but I am still confused as to why my initial approach isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For realising what's the problem here one has to understand that, when using a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data), it is evaluated **two times**.

1. it's evaluated for the elements...

> This key function is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]); the returned string is the element’s key.

2. ... then, it's evaluated again, this time for the data:

> The key function is then also evaluated for each new datum in data, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the group’s new data, with this as the group’s parent DOM element; the returned string is the datum’s key.

With that information in hand we can understand what's happening here: after binding `objects_with_values` as the data, the key function will return `undefined` when it runs for the elements, because those elements have no `key` property. Have a look:

```js
strings_only = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
objects_with_values = [{
  key: 'A',
  value: 1
}, {
  key: 'B',
  value: 2
}, {
  key: 'C',
  value: 3
}];

d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
  .data(strings_only, d => d)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'test');

selection_objects_with_values = d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
  .data(objects_with_values, d => {
    console.log(d.key);
    return d.key;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The `A, B, C,` you see after the 3 `undefined` correspond to the second run of the key function, as expected.

The solution is simple: if there is no `d.key`, look for `d` only:

```
.data(objects_with_values, d => d.key ? d.key : d);
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
strings_only = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
objects_with_values = [{
  key: 'A',
  value: 1
}, {
  key: 'B',
  value: 2
}, {
  key: 'C',
  value: 3
}];

// Bind the string data to the DOM with string values as keys
d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
  .data(strings_only, d => d)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'test');

// Bind again with the strings and I get the expected behavior
selection_strings_only = d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
  .data(strings_only, d => d);
console.log(selection_strings_only.size() == strings_only.length); // PASS
console.log(selection_strings_only.enter().size() == 0); // PASS

// Bind with the objects (same key value) and they end up in the enter() selection
selection_objects_with_values = d3.select('body').selectAll('div.test')
  .data(objects_with_values, d => d.key ? d.key : d);
console.log(selection_objects_with_values.size() == strings_only.length); // FAIL
console.log(selection_objects_with_values.enter().size() == 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fantastic! That makes complete sense now. I was assuming that data-binding stored the key on the elements (e.g. elem.__key__) instead of re-computing the element key for each new call to `.data()`. Thanks!